# Media Recording issue Android

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I am recording using Custom Media Recorder class and recording video some device Working ok but some device creating 0 length video.I don't know what is problem MediaRecording configuration.

```
            Camera mcamera
            mCamera.unlock();
            mrec.setCamera(mCamera);
            mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
            mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
            mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            if (cameraID != -1) {
                mrec.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(cameraID,
                        CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
            } else {
                mrec.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
            }

            mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
            mrec.setOutputFile(filename);
```

Plz help thank's in advance.

I m checking also hasprofile way

```
CamcorderProfile profile = null;

        if (CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_1080P))
            profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_1080P);
        else if (CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P))
            profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P);
        else if (CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P))
            profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P);
        else if (CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH))
            profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);

        if (cameraID != -1) {
            mrec.setProfile(profile);
              }
```

but this way getting issue in problem startunlock failed.

Comment: check i m update post @Michel but getting recording starting issue problem start-unlock failed

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you have to swap these line to:

```
        mrec.setOutputFile(filename);
        mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
```

Now, will it works? Let me know!